# Ruby 1.9.1 syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently deploying a rails application to heroku. The application is rails 2.3.3 and for some reason maybe because its a different ruby I am not getting a weird syntax error

**HERE IS MY ERROR**

```
Downloading postal codes.
rake aborted!
/app/app/models/postal_code.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
      when Integer: first(:conditions => { :code => code })
                   ^
/app/app/models/postal_code.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when Hash: first(:conditions => {...
          ^
/app/app/models/postal_code.rb:59: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

**HERE IS MY CODE FILE (postal_code.rb)**

```
11  def self.get(code)
12   case code
13    when Integer: first(:conditions => { :code => code })
14    when Hash: first(:conditions => { :city => code[:city], :state => code[:state] })
15    else raise InternalException.new("Invalid input.")
16    end
17  end


51    # now set min and max lat and long accordingly
52    area[:min_lat] = latitude - area[:lat_degrees]
53    area[:max_lat] = latitude + area[:lat_degrees]
54    area[:min_lon] = longitude - area[:lon_degrees]
55    area[:max_lon] = longitude + area[:lon_degrees]    
56      
57    area  
58  end
```

Any ideas what is it thats going wrong

Comment: Using colons in `when` statements became invalid syntax as of Ruby 1.9. You're probably using 1.8 on your local system. @Victor's answer below is correct. I __strongly__ recommend keeping your development environment on the same version of Ruby as your production environment. A lot of little things changed between 1.8 and 1.9 that may cause little issues like these.

Answer (score 6):

From the 1.9.1 NEWS file:

```
* Deprecated syntax
      o colon (:) instead of "then" in if/unless or case expression.
```

So you can't use a colon with a `case` anymore. You can use `then`:

```
case code
  when Integer then first(:conditions => { :code => code })
  when Hash    then first(:conditions => { :city => code[:city], :state => code[:state] })
  else raise InternalException.new("Invalid input.")
end
```

or newlines:

```
case code
  when Integer
    first(:conditions => { :code => code })
  when Hash
    first(:conditions => { :city => code[:city], :state => code[:state] })
  else
    raise InternalException.new("Invalid input.")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
def self.get(code)
 case code
  when Integer then first(:conditions => { :code => code })
  when Hash then first(:conditions => { :city => code[:city], :state => code[:state] })
  else raise InternalException.new("Invalid input.")
  end
end
```